# Can't bind events in Backbone.js view

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to create a view for a piece of HTML that has already rendered on the page. I can see that the view is being instantiated, but I can't bind to any events. Here is an example:

```
<html>
<head><!-- backbone, etc --></head>
<body>
  <div id="myElement">
    <button id="myButton">Click me</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    new MyApp.Views.ExampleView()
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My View (coffeescript):

```
class MyApp.Views.ExampleView extends Backbone.View

  el: $('#myElement')

  initialize: ->
    console.log 'initialized'

  events:
    'click #myButton': 'alertMe'

  alertMe: ->
    alert('hello!')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `#myElement` exist when your `MyApp.Views.ExampleView` is loaded? I don't see any `$ ->` wrappers anywhere...

Comment: It really does not make (much) sense to use `$('#myElement')` in the definition.  That gets the element when the custom view constructor is *defined*.  If you include a reference the script defining the views at the top of the page, the element isn't going to exist yet.  Just use '#myElement'.

Comment: @JayC Ah, good point. That may be my issue. I will try passing it in the constructor and see if that solves it.

Comment: @mu Now I realize you said the same thing as JayC. Forgot that $ -> means document ready in CoffeeScript.

Comment: Also, I may be going about this all wrong. I'm still new to Backbone. There may be a better way for defining views which don't need to be rendered.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@muistooshort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667943/cant-bind-events-in-backbone-js-view#comment20502313_14667943) and [@JayC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667943/cant-bind-events-in-backbone-js-view#comment20503129_14667943) I realized the reason the events were not binding was because my view was being defined before the document was ready (and defining `el` before the element had actually rendered). To fix this, you could define the view after the document was ready, or you could pass the element as an option when the view is instantiated:

```
<script>
  new MyApp.Views.ExampleView({el: $('#myElement')})
</script>
```

Or you can specify the selector as a string, and it will work correctly:

```
class MyApp.Views.ExampleView extends Backbone.View

  el: '#myElement'
```